# Where do nested function parameters come from?

Tags: javascript, function

In the following code, where does the parameter `chapters` comes from?
Same question for `error`, where does it come from?
I'd say they are passed on from the function `getChapters()`, together with `error`, but how can I know? How can I see from the debugger what values does `getChapters` returns?

```
player.getChapters().then(function(chapters) {
    // chapters = an array of chapters objects
}).catch(function(error) {
    // error
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`getChapters()` returns a promise. When the Promise resolves or rejects, a value gets passed in which the `.then` and `.catch` callbacks then receive:

```
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("this value goes in");
  }).then(function(value) {
    // value === "this value goes in"
  })
```

From the debugger, when `getChapters()` executes you cannot know these values, as usually `resolve` gets called later in time, thus the value is not known yet, and the return value is a *pending Promise*. However when you place a breakpoint into the callback, you can see `chapters` and you will also find that value in one of the internal slots of the Promise.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `getChapter` will return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which either "succeeds" (technically is "fulfilled") or fails (is "rejected").

In the former case the Promise will be fulfilled with a particular value, which will then be passed as the parameter (which you've chosen to call `chapters`) to the `.then` handler. If it's rejected, the "rejection reason", basically an error message, gets passed to the next `.catch` block in the chain - so in other words if `getChapter` fails, the `.catch` handler will be called with its parameter being passed the error message.

> How can I see from the debugger what values does `getChapters` returns?

Depends on what you really want. You can always step into `getChapters`, which may give you insight into what task that performs and how success or failure is determined. Otherwise, you can simply put breakpoints inside both the `.then` and `.catch` handlers to see which one is called and what parameter it gets.

Answer (score 1):

it seems the `getChapters` method on `player` object returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (like a web api call).

as described in MDN

> A Promise is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is created. It allows you to associate handlers with an asynchronous action's eventual success value or failure reason. This lets asynchronous methods return values like synchronous methods: instead of immediately returning the final value, the asynchronous method returns a promise to supply the value at some point in the future.

When you create a Promise there are two situation

1. Your Promise will resolve so you return (`resolve`) the value.
2. Your Promise will fail (for example with a HTTP error) so you return the error (`reject`)

when promise calls the `resolve` program will call the function in `then` with the result as param.
when promise calls the `reject` program will call the function in `catch` with error as param.

you can see the flow in the following diagram:
[image]

for debugging you can simply place a breakpoint inside `catch` or `then` functions and see the parameter value.

I highly suggest you study javascript [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to grasp how this happens.

Answer (score -1):

As this is a promise, so here the chapters is simply what the promise is going to return with successful call. I think this is checked by status code. If that is 200 then everything is ok else it passes an error to the catch method to handle that.